# Run function after Backbone.Router.navigate()

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I want to run a function (to render flash messages) after a backbone.navigate call. Is it possible? I currently hooked into the all event and check if eventname starts with "route:". But that triggers too early, before my messages are added... so I was thinking of running after the route completes

```
# intercept all router navigate and render flash messages if any
renderFlashMessengesOnNavigate = (evt) =>
  if evt.indexOf("route:") is 0 
    console.log "rendering messages after route ..."
    @flashMessenger.render()
window.appRouter.bind "all", renderFlashMessengesOnNavigate
window.authRouter.bind "all", renderFlashMessengesOnNavigate
window.userRouter.bind "all", renderFlashMessengesOnNavigate
```

Comment: define what you mean by a route "completing". Do you mean simply that the router has executed a route function? Or do you mean that the view created by the route function has completed rendering to its DOM element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var originalNavigate = Backbone.history.navigate;
Backbone.history.navigate = function(fragment, options){
    originalNavigate.apply(this, arguments);

    //your code here
}
```